# Why is localbuild for a REACT app is failing in nodeSetup task in Eclipse in Windows machine?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eclipse

Attempting to do a localbuild for a REACT app in a windows machine. It is failing in the nodeSetup task of the localbuild. I was getting an incompatible win32 on Yarn but that is corrected. Attached are the gradle refresh and localbuild dumps.

Installed are:
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Dev 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
node v12.10.0
npm v6.12.0-next.0

Removed and reinstalled node.js, yarn

From the localbuild dump:

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
>   boson:clean boson:clean took: [0.001] secs
>
> Task :nodeSetup FAILED
>   boson:nodeSetup boson:nodeSetup took: [0.379] secs
>   build completed
>   org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':nodeSetup'.
>   ...
>   Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find org.nodejs:node:8.15.0.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>     - https://.../repository/nodemodules/source/v8.15.0/ivy.xml
>     - https://.../repository/nodemodules/source/v8.15.0/node-v8.15.0-win-x64.zip
>   Required by:
>       project :